# CSS: Align link right of menu

Tags: css, hyperlink

I am trying to get a link next to my menu using CSS, since I haven't got much experience with CSS I can't get it to work. Currently the link is at the bottom left of the menu. The code for the Menu and link is this:

```
<div id="content">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="kwicks.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>  
<ul class="kwicks">  
  <li id="kwick1"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>  
  <li id="kwick2"><a href="klanten.php">Klanten</a></li>  
  <li id="kwick3"><a href="nieuwsbrieven.php">Nieuwsbrieven</a></li>  
  <li id="kwick4"><a href="subscriptions.php?page=1">Subscriptions</a></li>  
</ul>
<A href='logout.php'>Logout</A>
</div>
```

This will show like this:

[image]

What I would like to get is this:

[image]

I have tried to put it in a div and align that like this:

```
<div class="right">
 <A href='logout.php'>Logout</A>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.right {
text-align: right;
float: right;
}
```

But this will only place the link at the bottom right of the menu.
This is probably an easy thing to do for alot of you but I just can't get it to work. If anyone could show me how to get it right it would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've not provided any styles, I've made one from scratch, doesn't look like yours obviously but you can apply the same logic there, Float your menu to left, this will make some space empty on the right and your div will shift up, and will reside besides the floated menu, just in case if you've your menu centered on the page, I've provided a wrapper, you don't need that if your menu is not centered.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V9TEP/)

```
<div class="holder">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
    </ul>
    <div>Logout</div>
</div>

.holder {
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
}

ul {
    float: left;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

> Note: I am floating menu towards left, so don't forget to clear your
>   floats

Answer (score 1):

use `display:inline` instead.

```
<a href='logout.php' style="display:inline; float:left;">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's not an unique solution. I would put the `<ul>` and the `<a>` together inside a `<div>` and set style to the `<ul>` to be displayed inline:

```
<ul class="kwicks" style="display: inline;">
```

That's because the default behaviour of the `<ul>` tags is to be displayed in blocks, so they don't allow to display anything aside of them unless you change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the DIV before the UL it should float right correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul class="kwicks">  
  <li id="kwick1"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>  
  <li id="kwick2"><a href="klanten.php">Klanten</a></li>  
  <li id="kwick3"><a href="nieuwsbrieven.php">Nieuwsbrieven</a></li>  
  <li id="kwick4"><a href="subscriptions.php?page=1">Subscriptions</a></li>
  <li class="right"><A href='logout.php'>Logout</A></li>
</ul>
```